# Hive Join on String returns no matching

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to run a simple join on string values but getting no matching rows. However all the values are the same in both the tables

```
select l2.word,d.polarity from l2 join  dictionary d on (l2.word=d.word);

L2 table :
realtimesession_id      bigint                  None                
word                    string                  None   

Dictionary table :
realtimesession_id      bigint                  None                
word                    string                  None
```

I tried setting set `hive.auto.convert.join=true;`
but still no records matching. Please someone help.

Comment: How you have define the structure

Comment: Likely to be an issue with case. You could select the value of "word" from both tables and use a CASE statement to compare in the SELECT. That will at least tell you if you have an extra space or case issues

Answer (score 1):

Join on string will work. Just keep in mind that string matching will be **case-sensitive**.

Consider using functions like UPPER or LOWER.

For example,

```
select * from temp join new_temp on LOWER(temp.dept) = LOWER(new_temp.dept);
```

(Tested solution)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried standardizing the casing - hive is case-sensitive?  I usually use lower() when comparing strings to cut down on casing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Joining on strings is not the best practice, although if needed you should use:

select l2.word,d.polarity from l2 join dictionary d on (l2.word rlike d.word)